# How do I use samba in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, samba

I have Ubuntu Server running in virtualbox to which a directory is shared. I need to access this directory, probably even mount it, so that it's easily accessible for me.

When I had Ubuntu Desktop running in virtualbox in the same situation, I could access the folder simply by typing `smb://192.168.1.1/` into nautilus. I don't know how to achieve this in Server / terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) on the Ubuntu Wiki - should get your pointed in the right direction.